# DirectX render video

Tags: c++, video, directx, directx-11

Can someone explains how intro company logo or some other similar video sequences are presented in modern 3D games?

Is it pre rendered video sequence or it is rendered using DirectX to preserve quality, resolution and aspect ratio.

I understand that it may vary from company to company but I am searching for "best practice" since I can't find that in documentation.

Comment: Obviously, different companies may do it differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much always videos. Rendering a video with a different aspect ratio is almost always the same as cutting angles on a 3D scene rendering.

Also:
1) they're not always high resolution (sometimes, when playing 1080p, you can see that the video is actually 720p or much smaller)
2) to avoid quality issues, they can just record with high resolution and scale on small resolutions (it's not obvious to tell the difference between a scaled-down video and a perfect fit).

On a side note, some games may have 3D scenes but that means lags possible (before setting video settings), less complex visual effects and graphics quality (because rendering an animated movie is not the same as rendering a game, we're talking a million times longer in the most extreme cases).